# php codeIgniter: syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-aws

A aplicação php codeIgniter, que roda no windows, quando portada para o servidor dá o seguinte erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/givix/domains/givix.com.br/public_html/givix/application/libraries/Amazon3integration_lib.php on line 79
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Parsing Error
>
> Message: syntax error, unexpected '['
>
> Filename: libraries/Amazon3integration_lib.php
>
> Line Number: 79
>
> Backtrace:
>   (...)

Sendo que localmente não. Então acredito que não seja lógica, pensei ser alguma configuração do servidor.

Fiz algumas modificações no arquivo **.htaccess**, mas não sei alguém já teve algum problema parecido.

Lembando que a máquina local é windows e o servidor é linux. (cent os)

**Configuração local:**

- win 10
- easyphp 16
- Apache 2.4.18 x86
- PHP 5.6.19 x86
- MySQL 5.7.11 x86

**Configuração web:**

- vou verificar

A página que está setado o erro é esta:

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class amazon3integration_lib
{

    public $bucket_name = "teste";
    public $region = 'eu-west-1';
    public $version = 'latest';
    public $scheme = 'http';

    public $s3Client = null;

    public function __construct(array $config = array(), $reset = TRUE)
    {
         $reflection = new ReflectionClass($this);
        if ($reset === TRUE)
        {
                $defaults = $reflection->getDefaultProperties();
                foreach (array_keys($defaults) as $key)
                {
                        if ($key[0] === '_')
                        {
                                continue;
                        }

                        if (isset($config[$key]))
                        {
                                if ($reflection->hasMethod('set_'.$key))
                                {
                                        $this->{'set_'.$key}($config[$key]);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        $this->$key = $config[$key];
                                }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                $this->$key = $defaults[$key];
                        }
                }
        }
        else
        {
                foreach ($config as $key => &$value)
                {
                        if ($key[0] !== '_' && $reflection->hasProperty($key))
                        {
                                if ($reflection->hasMethod('set_'.$key))
                                {
                                        $this->{'set_'.$key}($value);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        $this->$key = $value;
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

        //AWS account setting
        define('AWS_ACCESS_KEY',"AWS-KEY");
        define('AWS_SECRET_KEY',"AWS-SECRET");

        define('BUCKET_NAME',$this->bucket_name);//The bucket name you want to use for your project
       // define('AWS_URL','http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/'.$this->bucket_name.'/');
        define('AWS_URL','http://'.$this->bucket_name.'.s3.amazonaws.com/');

        //check AWS access key is set or not
        if(trim(AWS_ACCESS_KEY,"{}")=="AWS_ACCESS_KEY")
        {
            exit("CI S3 Integration configuration error! Please input the AWS Access Key, "
                        . "AWS Secret Key and Bucket Name in applicatin/libraries/cis3integration_lib.php file");
        }
        require_once('amazonSdk/aws-autoloader.php');   

        //Create S3 client
        $sharedConfig = [
            'region'  => $this->region,
            'version' => $this->version,
            'scheme' => $this->scheme,
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    => AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
                'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
            ],
        ];
        $sdk = new Aws\Sdk($sharedConfig);
        $this->s3Client = $sdk->createS3();                
    }

    /**
     * Delete S3 Object
     *
     * @access public
     */     
    function delete_s3_object($file_path)
    {
            $response = $this->s3Client->deleteObject(array(
                'Bucket'     => $this->bucket_name,
                'Key'        => $file_path
            ));
            return true;
    }

    /**
     * Copy S3 Object
     *
     * @access public
     */ 
    function copy_s3_file($source,$destination)
    {
            $response = $this->s3Client->copyObject(array(
                'Bucket'     => $this->bucket_name,
                'Key'        => $destination,
                'CopySource' => "{$this->bucket_name}/{$source}",
            ));
            if($response['ObjectURL'])
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new bucket in already specified region
     *
     * @access public
     */ 
    function create_bucket($bucket_name="",$region="")
    {
            $promise = $this->s3Client->createBucketAsync(['Bucket' => $bucket_name]);
            try {
                $result = $promise->wait();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                //echo "exception";exit;
                //echo $e->getMessage();
               return false;
            }       
    }
}
```

O trecho que ele seta o erro é este:

```
 $sharedConfig = [
        'region'  => $this->region,
        'version' => $this->version,
        'scheme' => $this->scheme,
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
            'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: Pelo que vejo deve ser configuração do php, pois pelo erro esta falando que na sua abertura de array `[...]` não é reconhecido no servidor, se não me engano, só pode ser assim a partir da versão 5.5

Comment: correto amigo ... acabei de verificar aqui também...  agora descobri que a versão do meu servidor esta desatualizada, fiz a modificação pra sintaxe antiga do php aí passou blz, so que começou a dar erro dentra da lib ... voltei o codigo original e estou providenciando a atualizacao do servidor. para referencia o meu codigo modificado tinha ficado assim..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Substitui o código que diz estar com erro por esse:

```
$sharedConfig = array(
    'region'  => $this->region,
    'version' => $this->version,
    'scheme' => $this->scheme,
    'credentials' => array(
        'key'    => AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    ),
);
```

Possivelmente o server deve estar em uma versão do PHP anterior a 5.4 e por isso que ele não aceita a sintaxe acima.

Veja explicação no link:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php

Destaque do link diz:
**A partir do PHP 5.4 você também pode utilizar a sintaxe contraída de array, que troca array() por [].**

Recomendo solicitar a infra do server (ou host) que faça um upgrade do PHP, caso contrário você pode topar com outros erros parecidos quando tentar usar bibliotecas de terceiros com códigos mais atuais. (como é esse o caso pelo que vejo)

Boa sorte!